# How to deal with dynamic column counts in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

We are working on a platform which allows the user to create 'promotion' instances, wherein there are an arbitrary amount of pages and 'modules' associated with those pages. Each module has its own customizable collection of attributes. One of the modules I am developing is the entry form, which is the main component.

The form includes some default fields e.g. name, date of birth and email address. The module then allows the user to add as many additional fields of any type that they require (e.g. a '25 words or less' text field, extra opt-in checkboxes, etc).

I'm trying to plan out how I will deal with these X additional fields in terms of storage in MySQL. Sorting and filtering on these fields will be a requirement.

This seems like something that would be a known and solved problem, but I haven't had any luck either wording it correctly or coming across relevant information. I've had some thoughts while searching; but each has a downfall that makes me think there must be a better way:

1. Create a new table for each form module which contains the additional fields as new rows - this seems really messy / clunky.
2. Store the additional information in an extra row as JSON (or some other data format). Pull all the data into PHP, expand the JSON and work with all the data in PHP - we envision a high number of entries (5-10k) so I assume this would be too inefficient.
3. Having an upper limit on additional fields and appending a bunch of rows to the entries table i.e. 'custom1', 'custom2', 'custom3', etc. This seems very messy as well.

Looking again at point 2, I thought there might be a way to take the block of data in the extra row and create a derived table from it, but I haven't had any luck finding information around whether that's possible. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM( JSON_DECODE(entries.extra) ) ...
```

If this were possible, that would probably be my preference.

What is the correct way to approach this problem of needing a dynamic amount of additional rows?

Comment: Why not store these in narrow format, i.e. table with key-value pairs?

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution depends a lot on how you're going to use the data. All solutions have strengths and weaknesses, and you have to understand that you're basically trying to do something that relational databases were not designed for.

I gave a presentation about this topic earlier this year called [Extensible Data Modeling](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/extensible-data-modeling), in which I tried to provide a survey of different solutions, and their pros and cons.

You could also throw in the towel, and use a non-relational database to store non-relational data.